# Shape in "give something shape"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In wikipedia's gratitude letter, it reads

> Thank you for giving Wikipedia shape, and purpose, and momentum. Thank you for fitting us into your life.
>
> With immense gratitude.

Reference to "give something shape", what does shape mean here?

Answer (score 2):

Guided by the *OED*, we find that the word *shape* means the external form, outline, or contour of the surface of an object. Thus

> Q: What **shape** is the building?
>   A: It's a cube with one corner sheared off at a 45 degree angle.

This can extend metaphorically to the "appearance, structure, or properties" of abstract things that don't have a literal geometry. Compare the title of the 1936 film by H G Wells *Things to Come* that is also known as *The **Shape** of Things to Come*, which is about what the future will look like.

The word takes on the connotation of the "regular or proper form" of something, which we see in the idiomatic expression

> Plans are taking **shape**

Thus the shape of Wikipedia comprises its recognizable and regular features including its hyperlinking, crowd-sourced editorial method, standard organization of articles, and so on.